# What is Mrs. Ferrars putting into her mouth?

Tags: props, sense-and-sensibility-2008

In [*Sense and Sensibility (2008)*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0847150/), there is a scene where Mrs. Ferrars is biting into what looks like gold rocks.  As you can see from the picture, the object is hard and not very easy to bite into:

[image]

[image]

**What is Mrs. Ferrars putting into her mouth in this scene?  Is this some type of food?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These really look like [golden almond dragees](https://www.google.com/search?q=golden+almond+dragees).

In many parts of Europe, in Lebanon, they're part of wedding and baptism. Almond are roasted, then coated with sugar and as you mention it, can be pretty hard to bite.

In some recipes, the almond is replaced by chocolate. It makes it less expensive but the coating is still hard.

[image: almond dragees]

Comment: Also known as just 'sugared almonds' when not gold coated - especially in the UK, where few people these days can actually correctly pronounce dragees ;)) [more like drazhays, than anything starring Ru Paul]

Comment: Nice!  Makes sense that I have never heard of these as I'm American.  I'm assuming that they were a status symbol in 1811 as Mrs. Ferrars was very wealthy

Comment: Definately. Only wealthy people could afford these, even at the start of the 20th century. It was a fairly big amount of money for poor people. People at the wedding would get a small bag with 3 or 4 of them sometimes.

Comment: I was going to say these look like what I (AmE) would call golden Jordan almonds, but searching on Wikipedia for "Jordan almonds" led me to the dragée page. :)

Comment: Jordan, Lebanon, many countries in middle east have their tradition and recipe I believe. I mentioned only cultures I knew,  not surprised there are others :)

Comment: "In many parts of Europe, in Lebanon, they're part of wedding and baptism." For the past two decades at least, they haven't been around much. It's mostly a meditteranean (Italy, Greek) thing.

Comment: Like many traditions, they slowly disappear in many places. It seems that offering dragees was a tradition for christians, taking over greek and roman tradition of nuts given by godfather's and to newly weds.

Comment: Further research: seems like it was a 5-pieces bag for wedding/baptism, each almond representing a wish for the person(s).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag%C3%A9e

Comment: As an Italian, I confirm dragees are very popular here as token gifts for the participants to a celebration, in different colors: white for a wedding, blue or pink for a newborn, red for graduation. Gold would mark a 50th wedding anniversary, but they are much less common for this occasion.

Comment: Italy, France, Belgium, England, Greece, Jordany, Lebanon, Spain: already a few of "mediterranean countries and cultures". Not so weird as (except for California) the mediterranean area is where almond producers are